# Add Class to Divs in an order of another

Tags: jquery, html

I have 2 parent Divs containing same number of children like below;

```
<div class="parent_1">
    <div class="dir one">...</div>
    <div class="dir two">...</div>
    <div class="dir three">...</div>
    ....
</div> 

<div class="parent_2">
    <div class="dir">...</div>
    <div class="dir">...</div>
    <div class="dir">...</div>
    ...
</div>
```

I need to add the support classes of the parent_1 children's (`.one, .two, .three`) to the parent_2's children in the same order.

Number of children will be created dynamically and both parents will have the same number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var $children1 = $('.parent_1').children();

$('.parent_2').children().each(function(idx){
    $(this).addClass($children1.eq(idx).attr('class').replace(/dir\s+/, ''))
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3eGRn)

Another way I might look at is

```
var srcs = $('.parent_1').children().map(function(){
    return this.className.replace(/dir\s+/, '')
}).get();

$('.parent_2').children().each(function(idx){
    $(this).addClass(srcs[idx])
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uXyFU/)

Comment: Why aren't you using the `each`'s index? (And why do you bother answering people who post question against the SO rules?)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.parent_1 div').each(function(){
    $('.parent_2').find('div:eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').attr('class', $(this).attr('class'))
})
```